# Python list indices must be integer or slice not string

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image of code if not understandable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpUE2.png)

The image shows the code I have written, I want to swap item positions but I am getting list indices must be integer or slice not string. I have tried many different ways but still dont seem to get the hang of it.

```
choice = ""
lists = []
while True:

choice = input("Try out inv commands: ")
if choice == 'inv':
    print('Backpack has ' + str(len(lists)) + ' iteams: ' + str(lists))
elif 'inv pick' in choice:
    iteams1 = choice.split('inv pick ')
    iteams2 = iteams1[1].split(' ')
    try:
        if iteams2[1] != '':
            add = lists.insert(int(iteams2[1]), iteams2[0])
            print(str(iteams2), ' has been added')
    except IndexError:
        lists.extend(iteams2)
elif 'inv drop' in choice:
    iteams1 = choice.split('inv drop ')
    iteams2 = iteams1[-1].split(' ')
    if iteams2[-1] != '':
        removed = lists.remove(iteams2[0])
        print(str(iteams2), ' has been dropped')
elif 'inv swap' in choice:
    iteams1 = choice.split('inv swap')
    iteams2 = iteams1[1].split(' ')
    try:
        if iteams2[1] != '':
            pos1, pos2 = iteams2[2], iteams2[1]
            lists[pos1], lists[pos2] = lists[pos2], lists[pos1]
            print('swapped ')
    except IndexError:
        enter code herelists.extend(iteams2)
```

Comment: please paste code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code as images, instead paste it in the question and format the code.

Comment: try ```pos1, pos2 = int(iteams2[2]), int(iteams2[1])```

Comment: Please include your code as a [formatted code block](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image. [Why do we hate screenshots so much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/) | [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: @AnmolParida I just posted

Comment: @WasifHasan Hello Wasif thank you, I just posted the code

Answer (score 0):

Instead how about reversing the list?

```
lists.reverse()
```

If you use `reversed(lists)`, then it will print the list reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you see, on line 30 you assigned

```
pos1, pos2 = iteams[2], iteams[1]
```

That means that `pos1` and `pos2` are string variables. On line 31, you tried to use `lists[pos2]`, but that means `lists["something"]` instead of `lists[0]`. Always bear in mind what you value *and data type* assign to each variable.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, please follow the [guideline to ask questions in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to acommodate others in answering :)

To answer the question, the error says that it is caused by using a string on list indexes. Indeed, your variables are strings and you tried to use it in list indexes. e.g. `x[0]` to get element of a list on 0th position, but not `x['0']`

Instead, you can try using

```py
  pos1, pos2 = int(iteams[2]), int(iteams[1])
```

but I'd suggest rewriting the code to avoid casting types and future confusions

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you are giving strings as indices like the error mentions.

When you split the `choice` variable, it returns list of strings.
You need to convert those strings to integers or slices if you would like to access elements in those indices.

```
pos1, pos2 = int(iteams2[2]),int(iteams2[-1])
```

This works in your case I guess.

Don't forget to paste your code to your question next time, screenshot would be hard to read for people :)

Comment: @Dem i tried the method you suggested but i get this following error:     pos1, pos2 = int(iteams2[2]), int(iteams2[-1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'

Comment: @Naveed do you have numbers in `iteams2` list  or are you trying to give letters as indices ?

Comment: @Dem I am giving letters as indices, e.g. inv swap a b. With help of swap i want change the elements position based on the inputted values by the user not by index.

Comment: In a list you can't give letters as indices it should be integers. Instead of list maybe you can use dictionary and write it like `iteams2 = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }` . In this way you can return integers from `iteams2` with `iteams2['a']` .